# Testing promises with mocha chai and sinon

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I would like to test my promise resolve handler and promise rejection handler using `mocha`,`chai` and `sinon`.In addition,I have got the `sinon-chai` plugin and `sinon-stub-promise` plugin set up.

This is my block of require statements:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);
```

This is my test suite:

```
describe('Connect to github users',function(done){

    var api = require('../users'),
        onSuccess = api.onSuccess,
        onError = api.onReject; 
    console.dir(api);
    //the idea is not to test the async connection,the idea is to test 
    //async connection but to test how the results are handled.
    var resolveHandler,
        rejectHandler,
        getPromise,
        result;

    beforeEach(function(){
        resolveHandler = sinon.spy(onSuccess);
        rejectHandler = sinon.spy(onError);
        getPromise = sinon.stub().returnsPromise();
    });

    it('must obtain the result when promise is successful',function(){
        result = [...];//is an actual JSON array    
        getPromise.resolves(result);

        getPromise()
            .then(resolveHandler)
            .catch(rejectHandler);

        expect(resolveHandler).to.have.been.called();//error 
        expect(resolveHandler).to.have.returned(result);
        expect(rejectHandler).to.have.not.been.called();    
        done();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        resolveHandler.reset();
        rejectHandler.reset();
        getPromise.restore();
    });

});
```

I find myself getting this error:

```
 Connect to github users must obtain the result when promise is successful:
 TypeError: expect(...).to.have.been.called.toEqual is not a function
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vamsi\Do\testing_promises\test\githubUsersSpec.js:94:46)
```

Comment: Are stubbed promises synchronous?

Comment: The implementation is a `thenable` which can be chained with anything that has a `then` including a *real promise* which I wouldnt want to do,so I  use the `resolves` and `rejects` to test a handler only. I tried this after watching [this video](https://youtu.be/HHcEjAQ46Io?t=2213) where he captures arguments to jQuery ajax success callback,

Comment: Yeah, I just wondered that you expect the handlers to have been called right after you had them attached. Normal promises would fail this.

Answer (score 0):

The [sinon-with-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-with-promise) package should fit the bill for what you're trying to do. I ran into the same problem (except I didn't need to test reject cases) and it worked out nicely.

Answer (score -1):

This line of code here is wrong:

```
expect(resolveHandler).to.have.been.called();
```

`called` is just a property on the [spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) whose value is always a `boolean` and can be simply tested using `chai` like this:

```
expect(resolveHandler.called).to.equal(true);
```

Similarly instead of this line to confirm that the function has not rejected:

```
expect(rejectHandler).to.have.not.been.called();
```

Use this with `called` as a property:

```
expect(rejectHandler.called).to.equal(false);
```

Comment: The code is not wrong, he is trying to use `sinon-chai` and therefore `to.have.been.called` is valid code.